# How to delay execution in jQuery calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want to delay the execution upon mouse-over.

This is what I have so far

```
eventMouseover : function(calEvent, $event) {
    var $dialogContent = $("#event_show");
    resetForm($dialogContent);
    $($dialogContent).dialog({
        modal:true, 
        title: "Details of "+calEvent.title,
        body: "Name of Patitent",
        buttons : {
            cancel : function() {
                $dialogContent.dialog("destroy");
                $dialogContent.hide();
            }
        }
    }).show();

},
```

How can I delay so when user points for some seconds after execution should take place.

Comment: yaaa..bt delay and settimeout gives me error $($dialogContent).delay is not a function.if i m wrong suggest me how to add them.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to delay the action of an event is with:

```
var timeout;
$('#example').click(function(){
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    // your jQuery magic
  }, 200);
});
```

In this example your jQuery magic will be executed in **200 miliseconds**.

Comment: I suggest to use this example where your function eventMouseover is called, and by the way eventMouseover is a wrong name in this case because it has nothing to do with a mouseover itself.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
eventMouseover : function(calEvent, $event) {
    var timer = setTimeout(function(){

        var $dialogContent = $("#event_show");
        resetForm($dialogContent);

        $($dialogContent).dialog({
            modal:true, 
            title: "Details of "+calEvent.title,
            body: "Name of Patitent",
            buttons : {
                cancel : function() {
                    $dialogContent.dialog("destroy");
                    $dialogContent.hide();
                }
            }
        }).show();
    }, 2000);
}
```

This will execute the dialog code after 2 seconds. Replace the number 2000 with the number of miliseconds you require for the delay.